# C++ function as template argument

Tags: c++, function, templates, linker

While compiling my code, I keep getting the following linker error (the code compiles fine)

`` foo.cc:15: undefined reference to `void foo<int, int (*)(int)>(int*, unsigned long, int (*)(int))' ``

I'm fairly new to C++, and I'm pretty certain that my issue is coming from using template arguments, but I'm not sure where I am going wrong. The header for function `foo` and how it is being called is shown below

```
template<typename T, typename F>
void foo(T* a, size_t b, F c);
...
// neither of these work
foo(ptr,val,func);
foo<int, int (*)(int)>(ptr,val,func);
```

and my implementation of foo is compiling fine. I'm not sure where the issue is coming from.

Comment: Where are `ptr`, `val`, and `func` definitions?

Comment: ptr is an int*, val is a size_t, and func is `int bar(int a);`

Comment: BTW, even if you get this to work it is far from best practice. C++ provides superior mechanisms for passing functions -- use them.

Comment: such as? I initially wanted to use template arguments similar to <typename T, T (*F)(T)> but that didn't work either

Comment: Template parameters and function parameters are two completely different things in C++.

Comment: @wcochran This looks like standard practice to me. Pretty much all standard library function that accept callables use a single template parameter and pass them by value.

Comment: @super Best practices would have you pass function objects. You can'y even use the lambda facility in this case. This works but is fragile.

Comment: BTW, both cases work when I try it. You might want to give a fuller example.

Comment: moving the implementation from a cc to a header file fixed the issue

Comment: @wcochran Ofc you can pass in a lambda with this code. This is literally the exact same pattern used by the standard library. Not really sure what you're talking about.

Comment: @user13106509  -- yes -- the template needs to be somewhere where the compiler can instantiate it.

Comment: @super my bad -- you are right -- I guess I was focusing more on the instantiation of the template where a ptr is passed -- that part I wouldn't do.